# Grafana+Clickhouse+Docker. Can't connect to data source

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, clickhouse

I trying to connect to Clickhouse from Grafana. Both running locally in Docker. When I set all required settings in "Add data source" window and click 'Save and test' it immediately says 'Plugin health check failed'.

My docker compose file:

```yaml
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana
  clickhouse:
    image: clickhouse/clickhouse-server
    ports:
      - 8123:8123
      - 9000:9000
      - 9100:9100
      - 9440:9440
    volumes:
      # - ./run/clickhouse/users.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml
      - clickhouse-storage:/var/lib/clickhouse/
      - clickhouse-logs:/var/log/clickhouse-server
    environment:
      - CLICKHOUSE_USER=tymbaca
      - CLICKHOUSE_PASSWORD=qwerty
volumes:
  grafana-storage:
  clickhouse-storage:
  clickhouse-logs:
```

[image]
[image]

I also tryed to set `Server address` field to 192.168.0.17 (IPv4 from `ipconfig`) but it leads to `connection timeout`...

Comment: The request from grafana to clickhose is made from within the grafana container. As such, the clickhouse host name should be the name of the clickhouse container (`clickhouse`), not `localhost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How @Turing85 pointed, the problem was that the request from Grafana to Clickhouse was made from within the Grafana container.

Therefore the `Server address` must be not `localhost` but **Clickhouse container name** (`stackexchange-analyzer-clickhouse-1` in my case).

[image]

[image]

[image]